# Find the missing numbers in these flowers

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Can you figure out the pattern and solve for the three missing numbers?

All petals and centers each contain a single digit.

There is a unique solution for each missing number.

[image]

Hint 1:

> The order of the four petals on each flower does not matter. They can be rearranged in any order.

Hint 2:

> The center value is calculated using the four petals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answers are

Left petal in top

> $6$

Centre petal in centre

> $2$

Right petal in bottom

> $9$

Reasoning

> Multiply the four petals together and take the answer modulo $9$ to give the central square where we take $9$ (mod $9$) instead of $0$ (mod $9$), for this convention.

As pointed out by OP

> The central square is also the [digital root](https://brilliant.org/wiki/digital-root/) of the product of the petals.

Comment: Great job, that's correct! I based the answers on yesterday's date (June 29). The calculation I used for the central square is [digital root](https://brilliant.org/wiki/digital-root/) which is equivalent to $1+[(x-1)\text{ mod }9]$.